# readlink command misbehave after issueing pushd command in bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, readlink

I came across one complex problem I tried to explain it with simple example as below

In my system I have

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/temp$ pwd
/home/ubuntu/temp
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/temp$ ls
temp1  test.sh
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/temp$
```

In temp.sh I have

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Arg 0 = $0"
echo "Arg 1 = $1"
echo "Arg 0 Full Path $(readlink -f $0)"
echo "Arg 1 Full Path $(readlink -f $1)"
pushd /var/log
echo "Arg 0 = $0"
echo "Arg 1 = $1"
echo "Arg 0 Full Path $(readlink -f $0)"
echo "Arg 1 Full Path $(readlink -f $1)"
```

now I run at below way

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/temp$ ./test.sh temp1
Arg 0 = ./test.sh
Arg 1 = temp1
Arg 0 Full Path /home/ubuntu/temp/test.sh
Arg 1 Full Path /home/ubuntu/temp/temp1
/var/log ~/temp
Arg 0 = ./test.sh
Arg 1 = temp1
Arg 0 Full Path /var/log/test.sh
Arg 1 Full Path /var/log/temp1
```

**Here you can see `readlink` shows wrong path of the Arg0 and Arg1 files after issuing `pushd` command.** 
If I remove popd command then it prints fine.

So why here `readlink` misbehave?

Comment: Why do you think it's misbehaving? Given a relative path, `readlink` will interpret it relative to process working directory. If you want a path to be indifferent to pwd, you should save it as an absolute path. (please note that `pushd` will change pwd)

Comment: @rselmos Please make that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given relative paths, `readlink` will interpret them relative to process working directory, and output absolute paths (resolving symbolic links inbetween).

The key point here is the **process working directory** (aka current directory).

So `readlink ./path/to/file` will output `/tmp/path/to/file` if `/tmp` is the current directory (supposing no symbolic links).

The other command you're using, `pushd` will change the process working directory.

So in the sequence

```
readlink ./path/to/file
pushd /some/other/place
readlink ./path/to/file
```

both `readlink` will likely resolve to two different absolute paths.

No misbehavior here. All by design.

Answer (score 1):

`readlink` is behaving correctly here, only thing needs to be understood here is the behaviour of `pushd`. `pushd` is the command to change current directory stack. Let's understand from below picture.

[image]

Initially `test.sh` had some full path, after running `pushd` one more directory i.e (`/var/log`) is inserted into directory stack . 
Left most directory( or top most directory ) of stack becomes current directory.
And if you run `popd` , that means stack is getting empty from the top. As soon as you run `readlink -f test.sh` again after `popd` , you will have  initial directory . In your case it will be `/home/ubuntu/temp/test.sh`